# jQuery select JavaScript generated elements

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am using JavaScript to generate some HTML tables on the fly. After filling out this dynamic table, I employ jQuery to 'grab' some of the inputs and do some small calculations for form validation. However, my jQuery selector does not work with the dynamic HTML form. Can anyone give me some suggestions? Thanks!

Here is the code:

```
<script>
//generate HTML table
$('<tr><th><label for="id_CAM_1">Input:</label></th><td><select name="CAM_1_'+i+'" id="id_1_'+i+'"><option value="1">Option 1</option><option value="2">Option 2</option></select></td></tr>').appendTo('.table');

// jQuery selector, which does not work dynamically

$('select[name=CAM_1_'+i+']').change(function() {
            var ss1=$(this).val()
            alert(ss1)})
</script>
```

Comment: Use event delegation by passing a selector to the [`on`](http://api.jquery.com/on) method. It's much more resilient than trying to manage binding and rebinding events.

Comment: Is your code actually missing the `})` as above? otherwise it should work http://jsfiddle.net/mowglisanu/JKRGs/

Comment: I see 2-3 questions on this almost daily. [So many](http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=dynamically+created+elements) that I can't even bother to answer. :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following will detect all changes of all `select` elements that have a name that starts with `CAM_1_` in your `tableSelector`

```
$('tableSelector').on('change', 'select[name^="CAM_1_"]', function() {
    alert(this.value);
});
```

Comment: I guess the *starts with* selector was the real question then, eh? :)

Comment: You're plastering over the top of bugs elsewhere.  The code originally posted works fine (when you add the closing brackets).  It fails presumably because of some re-use of i in real code.

Answer (score 1):

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function() {
        $('<tr><th><label for="id_CAM_1">Input:</label></th><td><select name="CAM_1_'+i+'" id="id_1_'+i+'"><option value="1">Option 1</option><option value="2">Option 2</option></select></td></tr>')
            .appendTo('.table')
            .on('change', function() {
                alert(this.value);
        });
    });
</script>​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​
```

Answer (score 1):

I wanted to replicate your problem, but for me it works completely fine.  I did have to add the closing brackets (`})`) as these seemed to be missing from what you posted.  Do you get any errors in the console.  Check to see if you get any errors in the JavaScript console and whether you're using the latest version of jQuery.

```
<table class="table"></table>
<script src="http://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jQuery/jquery-1.7.2.min.js"></script>
<script>
i = 0;
//generate HTML table
$('<tr><th><label for="id_CAM_1">Input:</label></th><td><select name="CAM_1_'+i+'" id="id_1_'+i+'"><option value="1">Option 1</option><option value="2">Option 2</option></select></td></tr>').appendTo('.table');

// jQuery selector, which does not work dynamically

$('select[name=CAM_1_'+i+']').change(function() {
    var ss1=$(this).val()
    alert(ss1)
});
</script>
```

Comment: I forgot to add the }) in the post. Thanks!

Comment: I mean is this sufficient to fix your problem? because Neal's answer doesn't make a whole heap of sense given the way you've asked the question.  The code in the question now works fine.

Comment: It works now. I messed up 'i' in my real code. But I would like to switch to the 'on' approach.

Answer (score 0):

```
<script>
//generate HTML table
$('<tr><th><label for="id_CAM_1">Input:</label></th><td><select name="CAM_1_'+i+'"   id="id_1_'+i+'"><option value="1">Option 1</option><option value="2">Option 2</option></select></td></tr>').appendTo('.table');

// jQuery selector, which does not work dynamically

$('select[name=CAM_1_'+i+']').live("change",function() {
        var ss1=$(this).val()
        alert(ss1)})
</script>
```

---

so basically you need to use live method of jquery for dynamically generated html.